# get current "data-id" from element:

Tags: jquery, alert

having this list:

```
<ul class="ui-selectable" id="box">
<li data-id=100.100></li>
<li data-id=101.100></li>
<li data-id=102.100></li>
<li data-id=103.100></li>
<li data-id=104.100></li>
<li data-id=105.100></li>
<li data-id=106.100></li>
<li data-id=107.100></li>
<li data-id=108.100></li>
<li data-id=109.100></li>
<li data-id=110.100></li>
</ul>
```

and this jquery to get the data-id of the clicked listelement:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ui-selectable :not([data-id=""])').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().trigger('update');
});

$('.ui-selectable').on('update', function() {
    data = [];
    $(':not([data-id=""]).selected', this).each(function() {
        data.push( $(this).data('id') );
    });
    alert( $(this).data('id') );

});
});
```

but when i click a listelement, i get this alert-message:

```
"undefined"
```

anybody could tell me why and how to this correct?
greetings

Comment: Your `this` in the alert relates to `ui-selectable` which doesn't have an `id` data field

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$(this).attr('data-id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#box li').on('click',function(){
            alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
        });
    });
```

OR try In your code :

```
$('.ui-selectable li :not([data-id=""])').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().trigger('update');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in this case relates to

```
$('.ui-selectable').on('update', function() {
```

which doesn't have an `id` data field.

I don't know what you want to do, but you'll need to use `this` in a context where you're addressing one of the `<li>` elements, for example in

```
$('.ui-selectable :not([data-id=""])').click(function() {
                           <--------- put it here and it will work
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().trigger('update');
});
```